# Embedding resource in a C++/CLI project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

I'd like to embed some files (text files, maybe graphics) in a C++/CLI project -- preferably the same way I can do in C# project. This might be however impossible, as I found in this post: http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/571530-loading-markup-xamlreader-load-resource-file#post2240705. This was written three years ago, so maybe now there is some way to do this (in VS2k8)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Under C++/Cli project go to “Properties…”, then look under “Linker”, and then “Input”, you’ll see the list of embedded files under “Embed Managed Resource File”.

Comment: If you add a file here called test.dat, then you can access it like this:

Stream^ stm = Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->GetManifestResourceStream ("test.dat");

Comment: Also, check for nullptr just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Go to file properties, **General**, **Item Type**, select **Compiled Managed Resource**

Works in VS2013

To access resource in program:

```
Stream^ stream = Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->GetManifestResourceStream("file.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an embellishment of Tarydon's comment, showing how to save the embedded resource to a file:

```
using namespace System::IO;
...
String^ tmpFilename = System::IO::Path::GetTempFileName();
try
{
   Stream^ readStream = Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->GetManifestResourceStream("embedded_file_name.xyz");
   if(readStream != nullptr)
   {
       FileStream^ writeStream = gcnew FileStream(tmpFilename, FileMode::Create);
       readStream->CopyTo(writeStream);
       readStream->Close();
       writeStream->Close(); // Required to flush the buffer & have non-zero filesize
   }
}
catch (...)
{
    // Do something?
}
```