# How to embed a DLL within a C++/CLI executable?

Tags: c#, dll, c++-cli, embed

I'm on a C++/CLI project, and I'm trying to embed some DLL files (WPF custom control library) within my executable to avoid having over 9000 DLLs in the same folder.
There is a lot of information about embedding a C++/CLI DLL in a C# project (moreover, it is very simple), but the documentation about the reverse seems to be poor.

The closest solution I have found is here: [Embedding resource in a C++/CLI project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986205/embedding-resource-in-a-c-cli-project), but unfortunately I can't see my WPFWidget.dll in resources when I open the .exe file with Visual Studio (2008 or 2012).

I suppose I have to create a resource file, but I have never used this kind of file, and I'm a little lost because embedding a DLL in a resource file isn't intuitive to me.

Do you know a proper method which could help me? Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider using ILMerge?

Comment: this link may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63501666/1347910

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you compile your C# code with command line and create a .net module:

```
csc /target:module /addmodule:mfoo.obj bar.cs
```

Then you can merge this into the C++/CLI code with

```
#using <datei.netmodule>
```

Link with /LTCG. So you have only one C++/CLI DLL, with all the C# code inside...

See also:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/texblog/archive/2007/04/05/linking-native-c-into-c-applications.aspx
- [How to link C# and C++ assemblies into a single executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609056/how-to-link-c-sharp-and-c-assemblies-into-a-single-executable)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for repply.
The architecture of my project require that the WPF assembly is a DLL (not my choice ^^)

[SOLVED]
I have found a solution by using thses tow topics that I havn't saw before :
[embed DLL in MFC C++ EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808467/embed-dll-in-mfc-c-exe)
[Loading interdependent assemblies from C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978046/loading-interdependent-assemblies-from-c-cli)

Now the WPF is embedded in the rc file, and I can load it without adding it as reference.
Thank you !